# Azure Traffic Manager not working for Web Apps at Standard S1: Small plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-traffic-manager

I was doing some experiments with the Traffic Manager (new azure portal). I configured a new Azure Traffic Manager and added two Azure WebApp endpoints. 
But when trying to browse Traffic Manager endpoint I am getting

> This site can’t be reached, niktm.trafficmanager.net’s server DNS address could not be found.

The Status' of the TM endpoint are "Enabled" and both the Web apps are up and running. Also, the Azure Traffic Manager Monitoring status is Online.

[image]

I did this few times and still getting the same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm getting results for DNS lookup on that URL, maybe just browser cache?

Comment: Are you trying to open https://niktm.trafficmanager.net on your browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This site can’t be reached, niktm.trafficmanager.net’s server DNS address could not be found.

If I do not add any endpoints in my traffic manager, Monitor status is Inactive.

[image]

To verify DNS propagation using http://digwebinterface.com/, I could find similar result as yours `niktm.trafficmanager.net`.

[image]

And if I browse to `{my traffic manager name}.trafficmanager.net`, I could see same error message in browser.

[image]

If I add available endpoints for traffic manager, I will see Dig result like below, and I could browse to `{my traffic manager name}.trafficmanager.net`.

[image]

I suspect that your endpoints do not really add to traffic manager even though Azure portal shows they are enabled and online. You could try to create a new traffic manager and add endpoints to check if it will work fine, if Azure traffic manager still/always not work fine in your subscription, you may need to create a support ticket to fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, I had to delete the previous traffic manager and create a new one instead to get it working, 
Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Another reason why Azure Traffic Manager could not working with Azure App Service (Web App) is because you are using [Basic service-tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/), which doesn't support Traffic Manager feature. As a result, a Traffic Manger Profile has the `Inactive` status and `Stopped` for Endpoint monitor status.

Comment: Bingo! There should be some kind of warning in the portal if you attempt to point to a Web App in the Basic, Shared, or Free tier.